# Accessing Master Config environment names within templates

Tags: conditionals, focus-lab-master-config

I'm using Focus Lab's brilliant Master Config https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config but wondered if it is possible to use the ENV constant in a template?

Something like this?

```
{if ENV == 'staging'}Show this.{/if}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `{global:env}` and `{global:env_full}` by default. To add in extra variables see the `$master_global` array in config.master.php.